# How to get unique record by special column from a where method with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, this method return records as:

```
Post.where(valid: true)
# [
    [0] #<Post:11113892841> { :id => 1, :valid => 1, :user_id => 1},
    [1] #<Post:21113892841> { :id => 2, :valid => 1, :user_id => 2},
    [2] #<Post:31113892841> { :id => 3, :valid => 1, :user_id => 2},
    [3] #<Post:41113892841> { :id => 4, :valid => 1, :user_id => 3},
    ...
]
```

Want to get only unique `user_id` recoreds as:

```
[
    [0] #<Post:11113892841> { :id => 1, :valid => 1, :user_id => 1},
    [1] #<Post:21113892841> { :id => 2, :valid => 1, :user_id => 2},
    [2] #<Post:41113892841> { :id => 4, :valid => 1, :user_id => 3},
    ...
]
```

How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way of doing this is:

```
Post.where(valid: true).select('distinct(user_id)')
```

Comment: However the result is kind of worthless since you only select the user_id column.

Comment: @max I agree, however, I don't know how this is intended to be used.

Comment: Thank you. This way is good. I can add other columns after `user_id`.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use `.distinct` this will only return the user_id column:

```
irb(main):037:0> Post.select(:user_id).distinct
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "posts"."user_id" FROM "posts" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: nil, user_id: 1>]>
```

Which is kind of useless since you can't really do anything with the result set.

Unfortunately there is no good polyglot solution for this relatively simple problem due to difference in how the SQL standards are interpreted.

On **MySQL** you can use a GROUP BY statement:

```
Post.group(:user_id)
```

However this does not work on **Postgres**. (`column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause`). You could say that the only reason this works on MySQL is its allowance for potentially ambiguous queries - it does not comply to the SQL 1999 or 2003 standard.

On **Postgres** you should instead use `DISTICT ON(user_id)` as it will not allow the above query:

```
irb(main):058:0> Post.select("DISTINCT ON (posts.user_id) posts.*")
  Post Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT ON (posts.user_id) posts.* FROM "posts" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-09-14 11:46:12", updated_at: "2018-09-14 11:46:12">]>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to get multiple columns. Not only one with MySQL.

Comment: Then use .group(:user_id)